# Is there any special reason why a SQL AI index increases on a failed insert?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, innodb, auto-increment

For example, if I give a table's column a property to be unique, it requires to have something input on that column for it to execute the insert query. If I attempt to do an insert without that column data which makes it fail, the AI column index will have increased an additional amount of times that it failed the next time an insert is successful.

This means SQL increases that index anyway whether or not an insert has been successful. Any reason that it is made this way?

Comment: Perhaps better safe than sorry (there are plenty of numbers!)

Comment: It can be caused by various reasons. It's a well known gap issue. [InnoDB Record, Gap, and Next-Key Locks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-record-level-locks.html) related to logging, and the innards of the Engine

Comment: Now if you want to set out to "solve" this *problem*, many more have come before you, and have wasted days on it. Then wondered, why did I bother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an `INSERT` starts, it counts the number of rows to be inserted and bumps the AI by that amount.  Then it doles them out for the row(s).  If a row cannot be inserted (dup key, `ROLLBACK`, etc), well, the AI value has already been allocated.  It is now "burned".

Caution... There is one case where an AI can be reused:  `DELETE` the row with the highest AI, stop & restart mysqld, then the next `INSERT` will reuse that id.  This is because the re-opening of the table looks for `MAX(id)+1` to know what number to use next.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation of `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode` in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html)